# Regex workaround for applications that ignore case

Tags: regex, case-insensitive

I am trying to build a regex match in an application that ignore case in its queries. Unlike, say, Notepad++, in which one can turn a Case match off and on, this application (BitCurator) simply ignores Case. This, needless to add, makes case searching very difficult. For example, I want to search for the string (S) and do not want (s), which means something entirely different in this context.

```
\(S\)
```

in BitCurator returns both (s) and (S)!

Does anyone know of a workaround?
I suppose if the text string preceding (s) were consistent, I could omit those matches, but I am not sure that is the case (no pun intended). Thanks!

Comment: Which regex flavor do you use. In some you can enable or disable case insensitive match within the regex.

Comment: You know what? If there is no switch to turn on/off case and the regex treats [S] as [s], you are left with _NO_ options. I seriously _doubt_ that is the situation.

Answer (score 0):

In regex flavors like C#, Java you can use:

```
`(?i)`  to enable case insensitive match.
`(?-i)` to disable case insensitive match.
```

In PHP you can use:

```
`(?iJ)` to enable case insensitive match.
`(?-i)` to disable case insensitive match.
```

---

I can explain it using notepad++

If you have a document with:

Test
test

If you search with regex:
`(?-i)Test` ... then it will find the upper case word.
`(?-i)test` ... then it will find the lower case word.
No matter if you have match case enabled or not in the search window.

The same way most regex engines can be used.

---

I just tried it out and it worked:

```
bulk_extractor -f '(?-i)test' -o ~/Desktop/output ~/Desktop/input.txt
```

The results are written into `~/Desktop/output/find.txt`

Comment: What is the syntax for this?

Comment: Sorry, I did it in reverse. I also ran it in Notepad++ and it worked perfectly. I will pass this along to the person running BitCurator and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Our cataloger did try this, but on BitCurator, she got the following error:

Comment: “regular expression compile error '((?-i)\(S\))' flags=0”